# Reactivecocoa send new value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to reactivecocoa and I need help. I was searching and I couldn't figure it out. Let assume that I have UIPickerView. In that pickerView there are 4 options, for each language one for example german, english, spanish, french. On selected language I need to send back abbreviation english - en, french - fr... 
I'm using MVVM architecture and this is my method in my ViewController. In that method I bind ViewModel and selected properties.

```
- (void)bindeViewModel
{
  RAC(self, selectedLanguageAbbreviation) = self.languageViewModel.observeSelectedLanguage;
}
```

"observeSelectedLanguage" is my signal and its implementation is:

```
-(RACSignal *) observeSelectedLanguage
{
    @weakify(self);
    return [RACObserve(self, selectedLanguage) filter:^BOOL(NSString *value){
    @strongify(self);

    if (value == LocalizedString(myValueString(English)))
    {
        self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation = @"en";
        return self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation;
    }
    else if (value == LocalizedString(myValueString(German)))
    {
        self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation = @"ge";
        return self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation;
    }
    else if (value == LocalizedString(myValueString(French)))
    {
        self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation = @"fr";
        return self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation;

    }
    else if (value == LocalizedString(myValueString(Spanish)))
    {
        self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation = @"sp";
        return self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation;
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation = @"en";
        return self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation;
    }
 }];
}
```

"myValueString" is macro for returning string from enum, so English, French etc are part of enum. Can you help me and explain how to send abbreviation for selected language? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `map` instead of `filter`:

```
return [RACObserve(self, selectedLanguage) map:^id(NSString *value){
    ...
}];
```

**Additional suggestions**

Also, having side affects (setting `self.selectedLanguageAbbreviation`) inside the signals is not very good practice and should be avoided if possible. You could change your logic like this:

Explicitly bind values of `selectedLanguageAbbreviation` to `selectedLanguage` (in the view model's `-init`):

```
RAC(self, selectedLanguageAbbreviation) = [RACObserve(self, selectedLanguage) map:^id(NSString* language) {
    // do your mapping here
}];
```

And then you can remove `-observeSelectedLanguage` method and bind view controller's `selectedLanguageAbbreviation` directly to view model's `selectedLanguageAbbreviation` (if it is still necessary):

```
- (void)bindeViewModel
{
  RAC(self, selectedLanguageAbbreviation) = RACObserve(self.languageViewModel, selectedLanguageAbbreviation);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you with your additional suggestions, so I'm using it how you described it should be. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share full PickerView mapping, please?